# Run CakePHP Command on NetBeans in Ubuntu?

Tags: cakephp, netbeans

I'm trying execute CakePHP Command to generate Models/Controllers and Views but does not works. The Exception: `<There is no command available (perhaps error?>`. I'm using portable `Lampp`, the path to lampp is: `root@mypc#/opt/lampp`.

Looking for a solution I found to change timezone in `core.php` but doesn't works also.

How could I solve it ?

[image]

Comment: If you use ubuntu you have a bash. Why don't you use it?
I ususally do all my ./cake bake etc directly from there.

Comment: You need to set up the cake shell script system wide or call it directly from your current path. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console

Answer (score 0):

Could you submit your issue to the GitHub issues[1] with exact your steps and environments?

[1] https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans/issues